# Use display flex in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got the next code in HTML

```
<section class = "personal_proyects">
    <article>
        <div class = "personal_details">
            <h3>Canal YT: Codigo RM</h3>
            <p>EXPLICACIÓN DEL CANAL YT</p>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqURPBtGJzg&list=RDlqURPBtGJzg&start_radio=1" target="_blank">Ver canal</a>
        </div>
            
        <figure>
            <img src="images/YT.jpg" alt="Imagen canal YT" width=500>
        </figure>
            
    </article>
```

In my css

```
.personal_proyects,
section {
    display:flex;
}
```

I got another tags section in my html code, when i use the property flex my tags article inside my section with the class personal_proyect don't get align, how can i solve?

if i use the next sentence on css all the tags section use the display: flex, i only want for use that display for my tags section with the class "personal_proyects"

```
section {
    display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I always recommend new users visit [ask] for tips on asking questions in a way that best invites assistance from the community.  In the question above, there is not enough debugging details for the community to provide you with any helpful direction.  Could you add a [mcve] to this question as a snippet, so visitors to the question can see exactly the issue you are facing in code?  If possible, please include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and the specific way in which they deviate.

Answer (score 4):

Your class selector syntax wrong

`personal_proyects` class itself added on section.

So your correct syntax would be

```
section.personal_proyects{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
}
```